# React-Typescript: JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I wrote hoc withContex:

```
import React from 'react';
import permissionContext from 'context';

interface Props {
 Component: () => React.Component;
}

const withContext: React.FC<Props> = Component => {
 return function contextComponent(props: any) {
  return (
   <permissionContext.Consumer>
    {context => <Component {...props} permissionContext={context} />}
   </permissionContext.Consumer>
  );
 };
};

export default withContext;
```

and i have a problem with 'Component' prop:

```
JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

In the other component, with uses this hoc i see:

```
Argument of type 'FC<Props>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PropsWithChildren<Props>'.
Property 'Component' is missing in type 'FC<Props>' but required in type 'Props'.
```

*I'm cleary new in typescript.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`withContext` is not a React component but a function that returns one. Also component names should be capitalised. Try this:

```
const withContext = (Component: React.FC<Props>) => {
  return function contextComponent(props: any) {
    return (
      <permissionContext.Consumer>
        {context => <Component {...props} permissionContext={context} />}
      </permissionContext.Consumer>
    );
  };
};
```